# Winforms autoresizing a form with a status bar

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I am creating a windows Form that has autosize set to true, and AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink.

I stuck a simple control onto the form and ran the program. The form correctly resizes to only show the one control.

I then added a strip to the bottom of the form (I started with a DevExpress Bar, but then just to only use native controls, I stuck a statusStrip down there).

When I run the application this time, the autosized form is exactly the same size as the one without the status bar, and the control that I added is overlapping the status bar (I can see that the status bar is still actually there).

Why is this the case? Is this intentional? I would expect that the form shrinking would respect the fact that a status bar on the bottom of a form should not be overlapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AutoSize doesn't work very well when the controls are docked, etc.  Turn off the DockStyle on the StatusStrip to see the auto size work.

See Jared Par's [AutoSize and DockStyle.Fill don't mix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2007/11/21/autosize-and-dockstyle-fill-don-t-mix.aspx) blog.

> AutoSize and DockStyle.Fill don't mix well together.  Both properties exist to describe the size relationship relative to the rest of the control but they do so in conflicting ways.

Comment: I see that turning off the dockStyle will indeed make the other control not overlap. Unfortunately the form will no longer shrink the way that I would expect it to.

Comment: If you are expecting the StatusStrip to stay on the bottom, you have to position it yourself now.  The form will resize accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the statusStrip is set to dock. Because of that the control will just dock itself based on the form size and not the other way around.

Comment: I see that turning off the dockStyle will indeed make the other control not overlap. Unfortunately this isn't really an option because the form will no longer shrink the way that I would expect it to.